# Why isn't a time independent autocorrelation function sufficient for Wiener–Khinchin theorem?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, stationary-processes

The Wiener–Khinchin theorem says that for wide-sense stationary processes. If the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function exists, then it equals the power spectral density. Wide-sense stationary processes require a constant mean, and an autocorrelation function only dependent on the time lag. However, when I look through proofs of Wiener–Khinchin theorem, such as [https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~frank/notes/wk.pdf](https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/%7Efrank/notes/wk.pdf)
it looks like they only use the autocorrelation property. So, why is a constant mean also required?

Comment: Hi: If you don't have a constant mean, then it is not possible to seperate the mean from the rest of the signal. Therefore, any type of analysis that you do on the series, whether it be in the time domain or frequency domain,  will be incorrect. If the mean is constant, then it's easy enough to estimate it and get rid of it so that it is not included in the rest of the signal.